# ¿Por qué cuando creo un proyecto no viene con 'implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, app.config

Yo he visto a los demás tutoriales que cuando crea un proyecto se les crea esta linea de código:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto ocurre por que el `IDE` esta actualizado a `androidx`, es decir, el `SDK` de compilación viene configurado por defecto para `Android 9.0`. La linea que mencionas, es la librería de soporte que usaba `AndroidStudio` para compilación en versión de `android 8.0` (Oreo). Entonces:

**Esta linea:**

> implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

**Cambio a esta**

> implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

Por ende cada vez que crees un proyecto nuevo, el mismo se creara configurado para `android 9.0` automáticamente.

Para mas información acerca de esto, acá tienes la [documentación](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx) acerca del tema. Saludos y bienvenido a `stackoverflow`.

Comment: Y si quiero usar soporte con CardView como pongo la implementacion.

Comment: [Aqui](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) puedes encontrar los mapeos de como cambiaron desde el anterior artefacto de compilación, al actual. Allí esta el de cardView.

Comment: Te pido muchas gracias no sabia esa informacion. Y sabes como retoceder a 'Artefacto de la compilación anterior'